# Should my monoid be left- or right-biased?

Tags: haskell

The monoid instance for `[a]` is left-biased.  One way to
demonstrate what I'm aiming at is with the following two
definitions:

```
good ∷ Applicative f ⇒ Semigroup (f ()) ⇒ f ()
good = pure () <> good

bad ∷ Applicative f ⇒ Semigroup (f ()) ⇒ f ()
bad = bad <> pure ()
```

Here we can see that `good @[]` is productive whereas `bad @[]`
diverges.  The same issue can have similar consequences for
performance (runtime and memory usage).  So my question is, is
there a general guideline for whether I should design my
semigroup to be left- or right biased?  I'd argue that similar
things should be taken into consideration when writing/using
`Foldable`s.  Perhaps this is the reason that both `foldl` and
`foldr` are instance methods?

Answer (score 9):

(This is a bit opinion based, but I will answer anyway)

Other things being equal, I would make it left-biased.

I'm suggesting that only because there already are left-biased monoids (`[a]`), and I can't think of any existing right-biased ones. (Well, snoc-lists, but these are far less common.)

Further, left-to-right is a common order for "effects" like non-termination, or applicatives/monads. I would argue that most programmers are already used to such order of effect-sequencing.

Comment: `Last` is right-biased, but it's a special-purpose Monoid. There are also right-biased monads, but most of them are a bit weird and not strictly lawful (lazy state, lazy `ST`, etc.). The only simple, lawful, and somewhat important example that comes to mind is `Reader`.

Answer (score 5):

Left-biased makes sense because that's the way the `<>` operator associates naturally, without parentheses:

```
good = pure () <> pure () <> pure () <> ...
bad = ((... <> pure ()) <> pure()) <> pure ()
```

This is a bit of a chicken & egg of course, because this associativity was chosen so lists would perform properly. But there we are.

Comment: "that's the way `<>` associates" is a bit misleading since `<>` is _right_ associative. Still, that's precisely what we need to play along left-biased monoids. (+1)